# When I try adding rack-flash to my sinatra app it stops working

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I've been using `Rack::Flash` for a while to display flash notices on responses in my Sinatra apps. Since I upgraded to Sinatra 1.3.2, the app crashes, logging the following whenever I make a request to the server:

```
!! Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
```

The simplified code looks like this:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'rack-flash'

enable :sessions
use Rack::Flash

get "/" do
  "Hello World"
end
```

Any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

rack-flash doesn't work with the latest versions of rack. Try [sinatra-flash](https://github.com/SFEley/sinatra-flash) instead.

Comment: I appreciate your help. That should be it!